# Install .deb file from git repo on apt-get install

Tags: apt

I have a .deb file built and checked-in into my git repository. I want to add this git repository url, as an apt-get repo in the debian system. So, everytime, i do `apt-get install apt-repo-demo`, it must fetch the latest checked-in debian file from git and install it.

How can i do this?

I use ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure I understand the situation, you have a git repository which is accessible via a protocol that `apt` will understand, like `http` or `ftp`, which contains `.deb` packages which you would like to serve over the network as a remote repository.

This wont be terribly difficult because it seems like you already have the transfer mechanism in place. All that remains is to generate the meta-data which identifies your folder as a repository which aptitude expects to find.

Install the package `dpkg-dev`.

Then run the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/your/repository
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Don't worry about the `/dev/null` too much. `dpkg-scanpackages` expects an override file to be passed which you don't need to bother with so you're passing it an empty file.

Then on your client all you need to do is edit your `sources.list` with

```
deb protocol://theurlofyourhost.com/the/path/to/your/repo
```

The command `dpkg-scanpackages` will have to be run every time you update a package and how you accomplish that will depend on what works best for you. A `cron` job running every few minutes, a custom service using `inotify` and the `inotifywait` command, or just a simple wrapper script to commit your changes run the command.

Comment: http://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository... this link has a detailed information about how i can set it up with just one apache server....